# TWIG: capitalize makes other letters small

Tags: symfony, twig, capitalization

I have a variable with this content `"i want HTML"`

When I make `capitalize` `{{ variable|capitalize }}` the sentence is: `"I want html"`

How can I write only the FIRST letter of the sentence big in TWIG and the others stay like they are!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [create a new filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) that return your string using the php function `ucfirst`.

Comment: Right, I created an own extension like its shown here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Definitely a way to go, although I had some problems with `ucfirst` before (didn't work, gave up ultimately)

Answer (score 25):

You can just do this:

```
{{ variable[:1]|upper ~ variable[1:] }}
```

from https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1652

Answer (score 6):

Just to illustrate a good twig practice solution, you can create a custom Utilities Twig Extension and consider Multibyte String (mb) for strings starting with accents, to work properly:

```
use Twig_SimpleFilter;

class UtilitiesExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('ucfirst', 
                array($this, 'ucFirst'), array('needs_environment' => true)
            ),
        );
    }

    public function ucFirst(Twig_Environment $env, $string)
    {
        if (null !== $charset = $env->getCharset()) {
            $prefix = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $charset), $charset);
            $suffix = mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string, $charset));
            return sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, $suffix); 
        }
        return ucfirst(strtolower($string));
    }
}
```

Then you can call such filter from a twig file in the way. Accents even work:

```
{{ 'étudiant de PHP' | ucfirst }}
```

Results in: "Étudiant de PHP"

Answer (score 4):

`ucfirst` is Ok but doesn't handle accents correctly. So my `ucfirst` filter looks like that:

```
/**
 * ucfirst with handling of accents.
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $encoding
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function ucfirst($value, $encoding = 'UTF8')
{
    $strlen = mb_strlen($value, $encoding);
    $firstChar = mb_substr($value, 0, 1, $encoding);
    $then = mb_substr($value, 1, $strlen - 1, $encoding);

    return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
}
```

-

```
$test1 = $this->container->get('app.twig.text.extension')->ucfirst('i want HTML');
$test2 = $this->container->get('app.twig.text.extension')->ucfirst('éllo');
dump($test1, $test2); die();
```

Will output:

```
"I want HTML"
"Éllo"
```

The same with `ucfirst` will output:

```
"I want HTML"
"éllo"
```

Comment: could also implement **needs_environment** to work with global env encoding

Answer (score 4):

You can create a filter very easily for `ucfirst()`:

```
//in PHP - during setup
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ucfirst', 'ucfirst'));

//in Twig usage
{% set variable = 'i want html' %}
{{ variable|ucfirst }} //output: "I want html"
```

You can create a filter if you intend to use `strtoupper()` on "HTML"

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: @tremby corrected, I misread the question. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1):

You should select the first word of the sentence and just capitalize only it:

```
{% set foo = "i want HTML" | split(' ', 2) %}
{{ foo[0] | capitalize }} {{ foo[1] }}{% set foo = "i want HTML" | split(' ', 2) %}
{{ foo[0] | capitalize }} {{ foo[1] }}
```

Hope to be helpful! See a sample here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fzNNT/18/)

Comment: WHe I have a sentence like "back to HTML" the output with your suggest is "Back". The other words are eleminated

Comment: Ok, sorry, you should append the string remaining. Try this way:
{% set foo = "I want html" | split(' ', 2) %}
{{ foo[0] | capitalize }} {{ foo[1] }}

Comment: The problem is that it doesnt work with only one word. So there is an error because key "1" does not exist. I think its too complicated in twig for only writing the first letter in uppercase

Comment: you would be better of with just doing a bit more work and writing a filter twig extension to do that - especially if you plan to use this in multiple occasions

Comment: mmh... it's quite strange... I've tryed this:

{% set foo = "i want HTML" | split(' ', 2) %}
{{ foo[0] | capitalize }} {{ foo[1] }}

and it works
pleasde see http://jsfiddle.net/fzNNT/18/

Comment: Yes i twokrs, but when i only have one word like "hello", this doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

`Twig_SimpleFilter` is deprecated. I have created a working solution that uses the current `Twig_Filter` and handles accents (taken from COil code). The example demonstrates Twig custom filter in a standalone application.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;

$loader = new FilesystemLoader(__DIR__ . '/templates');
$twig = new Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_Filter('accFirst', 'accFirst'));

$sentence = 'šumivé víno';

echo $twig->render('customfilter.html.twig',
    ['sentence' => $sentence]);

function accFirst($value, $encoding = 'UTF8')
{
    $strlen = mb_strlen($value, $encoding);
    $firstChar = mb_substr($value, 0, 1, $encoding);
    $rest = mb_substr($value, 1, $strlen - 1, $encoding);

    return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $rest;
}
```

The following is the template file. The template file is located in the `templates` directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Custom filter</title>
</head>

<body>  

    <p>
     {{ sentence | accFirst }} 
    </p>      

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with native code is:

```
{{ variable|first|capitalize ~ variable|slice(1) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

`{{ variable | title }}`

It will give you Output:

`I Want Html`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy Solution:

```
{{ variable|title|replace({ 'Html': 'HTML' }) }}
```

Output:

```
I Want HTML
```

Answer (score -3):

The following solution will work for any phrase, but it will only fix the "HTML" word and not other acronyms that may need to be fixed too:

```
{{ variable|capitalize|replace({ 'html': 'HTML' }) }}
```

Comment: No, that won't work: the rest of the string should stay as given, but `capitalize` will lowercase everything